# No "Compatibility View" Options

Tags: group-policy

I'm working on setting up a GPO to push out some compatibility view settings for IE. But in my Group Policy editor there are no "Compatibility View" settings. I'm looking in Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer under both User and Computer settings. I'm working from a Windows 7 machine, but I've also tried working from my Server 2008R2 machine as well. Any ideas?